# Bounded orthogonal sequence in unitary space.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inner-products

Let X be an unitary space. a(n) is bounded orthogonal sequence (infinite). Prove that for every point x in X we have convergence:
<x, a(n)> -> 0 when n-> infinity.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each $i$, define $u_i=a(i)/\|a(i)\|$ when $a(i)\ne0$, or $u_i=0$ otherwise. Let $y_k=\sum_{i=1}^k\langle x,u_i\rangle\, u_i$. One can readily verify that $y_k$ is orthogonal to $x-y_k$, i.e., $\langle x-y_k,\,y_k\rangle=0$. Therefore $\|x\|^2=\|x-y_k\|^2+\|y_k\|^2$ and
$$\|x\|^2\ge\|y_k\|^2=\sum_{i=1}^k|\langle x,u_i\rangle|^2$$
for every $k$. Hence $\sum_{i=1}^\infty|\langle x,u_i\rangle|^2$ is a convergent series of real numbers and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,u_i\rangle=0$.

Finally, by assumption, $\|a(i)\|\le C$ for some positive constant $C$. Therefore
$$0\le\lim_{n\to\infty}|\langle x,a(i)\rangle|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|a(i)\||\langle x,u_i\rangle|\le \lim_{n\to\infty}C|\langle x,u_i\rangle|=0$$
and thus $\lim_{n\to\infty}\langle x,a(i)\rangle=0$.

Comment: @Fraktal Fixed. It's a minor glitch since $\{a(i)\}$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm a bit rusty on the subject thus I hope it's correct)

Recall that a non-negative series might converge if it is a zero-sequence.

Now pick $x\in X$ so that $\|x\|^2=M<\infty$ and complete the sequence $a(n)$ to a bounded orthogonal basis of your space. Then since it's a basis you can decompose

$$X=\sum_n \frac{1}{\|a(n)\|}\langle X,a(n) \rangle\cdot a(n)$$

so that by orthogonality

$$X\cdot X= \sum_n \langle X,a(n)\rangle^2=M <\infty$$
and thus $\langle X,a(n)\rangle$ must be a zero-sequence.